# Getting rotation correct after setting mesh quaternion from unit vectors in threejs

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, rotation, quaternions

I am having an issue where I am trying to align a model's local vector to another vector, but I'm having trouble understanding how to rotate my object the correct way.

I'm trying to take a mesh's local vector and orient it to a global orientation.

```
let localVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1).normalize();
let otherVector = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0).normalize();
mesh.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(meshNormal, otherVector)
```

Which I can do just fine, but I can't figure out how to calculate the how far it rotates around otherVector axis. As I want my object to stay flat.

Here is a jsfiddle trying to show what I mean.
https://jsfiddle.net/h20hnn3n/49/

On the left is the original model, in the middle is what I want, but on the right is what I am getting.

I want to just be able to run

```
mesh.rotateOnAxis(someVector, someRotation)
```

and get it to stay flat.

I'm trying to figure out a consistent way that no matter what two vectors, I use I can get the model to stay flat.

Is there a way to calculate the right way to do this?

Edit: 
To clarify on this https://jsfiddle.net/hrdottgq/2/ I'm trying to figure out what to put in place of

```
let zUp = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0)
zUp.applyQuaternion(new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(otherVector, meshNormal))
let angle = -Math.atan2(zUp.x, zUp.z);
```

In order to rotate on the axis

```
rotated.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), angle)
```

Comment: [This updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h20hnn3n/50/) should help you. Remember, objects (other than cameras), by default, look up their local positive-z axis.

Comment: Thanks for some of the tips on cleaning that up, but it doesn't really help me. The problem arises when the "otherVector" is in both x and y "meshNormal" so when I switch that back over to "new THREE.Vector3(Math.random(), Math.random(), 0)" I still don't know how to fix the rotation.